# Why did the Stack Overflow blog switch back to WordPress from Jekyll?

Tags: support, blog, technology

Why did the Stack Overflow blog switch back to WordPress from Jekyll again? It was originally on WordPress, then switched to Jekyll for some time, and now it's been switched back.

This screenshot from Developer Tools shows that it's now on WordPress:

[image]

And this login page:

[image]

Did Jekyll fail to scale well, or is there some other reason to switch back to WordPress?

Comment: IIRC the content editing process didn't fit well with the barebone, push, branch merge strategy required with Jekyll.